# convert php to javascript #1

Tags: php, javascript, converters

I'm trying to convert this awesome pathfinding php function from http://granularreverb.com/a_star.php to javascript.

PHP function

```
function path_float(&$heap, &$values, $i, $index) {
        for (; $i; $i = $j) {
            $j = ($i + $i%2)/2 - 1;
            if ($values[$heap[$j]] < $values[$index])
                break;
            $heap[$i] = $heap[$j];
        }
        $heap[$i] = $index;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT function

```
var $path_f;
var $path_h;
var $path_g;
var $path_open_heap;


function path_float($path_open_heap, $path_f, i, index) { // return heap & values

    var j;

    for (; i; i = j) {

        j = (parseInt(i) + parseInt(i)%2)/2 - 1;

            if($path_f[$path_open_heap[j]] < $path_f[index] ){
            break;
        }

      $path_open_heap[i] = $path_open_heap[j];

    }
    $path_open_heap[i] = index;

}
```

I'm not sure if javascript understands for() without all elements? If i try to execute javascript function my browser freezes.

P.s. i'm not interested in pre-written js pathdindings, because i need identical php and js function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would suggest that you have an infinite loop going on.  Have you tried debugging this at all?  Adding in some `console.debug()` lines to see what values are?  If the browser did not like your syntax then it would give you a parse error.

Comment: i dont get js errors, its all about infinite loop i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` without all the elements in javascript similar to PHP. So that is not the problem.

I think the problem is the float that is returned to J. it could be that it never realy is `0` but might be some large float like `0.00000000001` or something and thus never evaluates to false. Unfortunately I cannot test it as You did not provide any input values.

Try the following:

```
var $path_f;
var $path_h;
var $path_g;
var $path_open_heap;


function path_float($path_open_heap, $path_f, i, index) { // return heap & values

    var j;

    for (; i; i = parseInt(j)) {

        j = (parseInt(i) + parseInt(i)%2)/2 - 1;

            if($path_f[$path_open_heap[j]] < $path_f[index] ){
            break;
        }

      $path_open_heap[i] = $path_open_heap[j];

    }
    $path_open_heap[i] = index;

}
```